# How to output N lines with N, N-1, .., 1 characters per line

Tags: python

Currently learning python and have ran into a problem how do i get it to do this? The example below is the problem.

```
Number of lines: 5 *User inputs number*
xxxxx

xxxx

xxx

xx

x *Then it prints any number of 'x' backwards.
```

So it counts backwards the number you put in, so for example if it was 5 it will display 5 'x's and count them down. Also it needs the user to input any number and it will perform that action.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Ah, you want to get a number from the user, than print `num` x's, followed by `num-1` x's, etc?

Comment: Sorry i didn't make it clear enough. Hope the edit helps

Comment: Did you make an attempt to do your own homework before posting the assignment here?

Comment: Yes sir i tried but i'm just learning this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In that case, can you show us what you tried instead of just pasting the assignment text here and then pasting the answer into your teacher's inbox?

Comment: It's not for an assignment. However i could give you what i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
from __future__ import print_function

num = int(input("Number of lines: "))  # Use raw_input() on Python 2

for count in range(num, 0, -1):
    print('x' * count)
    print()
```

Demo:

```
$ ./SO_32061218.py 
Number of lines: 5
xxxxx

xxxx

xxx

xx

x
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: How would i get rid of the spaces?

Comment: @ThePussWhisperer, you had them in your example output, but if you don't want them, take out that last, empty `print()`.

Comment: @ThePussWhisperer, you should upvote all good answers, including and not limited to the accepted answer.

Comment: After the edit it this is a very pythonic way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate over a range in descending order:

```
n = int(input("Number of lines: "))
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print('x' * i)
```

You should replace `input()` with `raw_input()` if you are using Python 2.

As an alternative you can generate the 'x' sequences in ascending order and then reverse them prior to output.

```
n = int(input("Number of lines: "))
print(*reversed(['x' * i for i in range(1, n+1)]), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Just getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: OK, you are using Python 3 in which  `print` is a function. I've updated the answer.